# curl certification issue when using pyenv to build new environment

Tags: python, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate, pyenv

When I trying to build an environment using pyenv:
`pyenv install 3.10.4`, I got an error:

```
 Downloading Python-3.10.4.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.4/Python-3.10.4.tar.xz
error: failed to download Python-3.10.4.tar.xz

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.04 using python-build 20180424)

Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20220919130851.22961.log

Last 10 log lines:
/tmp/python-build.20220919130851.22961 ~
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

And when i try: `curl -v https://google.com`, SSL certification verify ok

```
*   Trying 74.125.24.138:443...
* Connected to google.com (74.125.24.138) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.google.com
*  start date: Aug 29 08:16:33 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 21 08:16:32 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "google.com" matched cert's "google.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services LLC; CN=GTS CA 1C3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
```

But when i try: And when i try: `curl -v https://www.python.org`, unable to get local certification issuer.

```
*   Trying 199.232.44.223:443...
* Connected to www.python.org (199.232.44.223) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

It seems like my CAcert doesn't recognize python.org, and because I'm using pyenv to build a python environment, i can't bypass certification check by curl(by using -insecure). Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try that

1. open ~/.bashrc and add the following line and save it

   export CURL_CA_BUNDLE="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
2. sudo update-ca-certificates -f
3. source ~/.bashrc

Then try to install using pyenv again

Reference of the answer [reference](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/3843#issuecomment-896468803)